# Counting number of coloured pixels in an image

Tags: matlab

I have an image of a Jacaranda tree (jpeg) and i want to count the number of 'purple' pixels in this image using matlab.

Comment: How are you defining purple?

Answer (score 3):

The hard thing about this question is -> **How do you define purple?**

Before answering that lets introduce [**HSV color space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). 
In this color space, unlike in RGB, there is a single value that describes colors, while the others are saturation and "light" (see wikipedia or [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685724/to-categorize-jet-colormap-by-pixels-of-some-colors/28691726#28691726) for more info about HSV). This means that just by looking at H we can know which color something is. The first thing we will do is put our image in HSV.

```
hsv_image = rgb2hsv(rgb_image)
```

Now we need to know which values of H are "purple". We can see a rough approximation of where purple is [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357732/hsv-color-ranges-table), where it is identified in around 300 degrees of Hue. If, instead, we look a bit deeper to the wikipedia page of [Shades of purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_purple)*. There, we can see that the shades of purple listed are about 270-320 Hue values.

If we like this approximation, then we can just select the pixels of the image with that amount of H by

```
H=hsv_image(:,:,1);
```

and then just select the ones that are in the desired range

```
purple=H<320 && H> 270;
```

Or in just one go

```
purple=hsv_image(:,:,1)<320 && hsv_image(:,:,1)> 270;
```

Then we just need to count.

```
N_purple=sum(purple(:))
```

<sub>*If you were asking for gray the wikipedia page would be confusing</sub>