# Create a plot with a 2D colourmap depending on two variables

Tags: matlab, colors, colormap

I want to display an image (e.g.[`imshow`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html)) and use a colormap to represent the values of my data points.

However, [`colormap`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) only gives the option to be dependent on a single variable, but I want a "2D colormap" which depends on two variables.

For example I have a simple image 2x2 pixels:

> img = [
>
> 1 1 5 6;
>
> 1 2 8 7;
>
> 2 1 4 3;
>
> 2 2 15 3]

Here the first two values of each row are the coordinates, the other two are the values describing the pixel (call them `x` and `y`).

When displaying the image I want to use a 2D colormap. For example something like this, which picks a colour depending on both variables (`x` and `y`):

[image]

Is there an option in MATLAB do to this, possibly in one of the extra toolboxes?

If not can this be done manually? I was thinking by overlaying a grey scale image given from the first value over a colormap image given by the second value a similar effect could be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2D colormap you are actually using the HSV color space.

Basically, your x axis is Hue, and Y axis is Saturation. You can convert any value into this space if its properly scaled. If you make sure that you scale your 3rd and 4rd column in the `[0-1]` interval you can easily do

```
colorRGB=hsv2rgb([val3,val4,0.5]);
```

If you perform this operation for each pixel, you'll get the image you want.

I gave a extended explanation of how HSV works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685724/to-categorize-jet-colormap-by-pixels-of-some-colors)

Comment: Great, thanks for your quick reply and your extended explanation :) I'll try to implement it.

Comment: @Johannes ask anything if you need, ;). If it works, dont forget to accept the answer as valid

Comment: seems to be working :) How would I be able to display a colour bar or better a slice of the color cylinder which corresponds to my values?

Comment: @Johannes you can not , by default display a 2D colorbar.... Unless you just createa a subplot and draw the whole thing!

Comment: Okay, got that working as well. Final question: Since I had to convert my values into the `[0-1]` interval the colorbar is from 0 to 1. Is it possible to use the original values to show with the colorbar?

Comment: @Johannes just change the values of `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` or the corresponding ones int he way you are plorting that colorbar. If you have problems dont hesitate to open a new question

Comment: Okay, I'll open a new questions, because I'm still a bit stuck with it.

Comment: Posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010253/modify-colorbar-ticks-and-color-range)