# How to convert an image matrix to nx3, so that n is # pixels and R,G,B values in each column

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

what iam trying to do is do a maximum likelihood estimation on images.
I want to learn where a yellow ball is in an image,so open up 15 images and mask the ball get its R,G,B values and get its mean and covarience matrix.
And use this parameters on other test images to get the yellow ball.
I found out mean and variance of the multivariate guassian distribution
such that mean mu = 1x3 where each column is  [R G B]
and sigma = 3x3
I am no matlab expert iam doing this as part of an assignment in coursera i got this code here which was provided to me `

```
 imagepath = './train';
 Samples = [];
for k=1:15 
% Load image
I = imread(sprintf('%s/%03d.png',imagepath,k));
% I = im2double(I);%edited
% You may consider other color space than RGB
R = I(:,:,1);
G = I(:,:,2);
B = I(:,:,3);

% Collect samples 
disp('');
disp('INTRUCTION: Click along the boundary of the ball. Double-click when you get back to the initial point.')
disp('INTRUCTION: You can maximize the window size of the figure for precise clicks.')
figure(1), 
mask = roipoly(I); 
figure(2), imshow(mask); title('Mask');
sample_ind = find(mask > 0);

R = R(sample_ind);
G = G(sample_ind);
B = B(sample_ind);


 Samples = [Samples; [R G B]];
disp(size(Samples))
disp(k)
disp('INTRUCTION: Press any key to continue. (Ctrl+c to exit)')
pause
end
```

this code gave  me a matrix which is nx3 and i did found out the mean and covariance matrix from this....this is the learning part

Now i have to apply this learned mean and sigma into a test image to get its multivariate guassian probability so that i can find the yellow ball in the image.(because my mean is a 1x3 matrix i need the image to be in nx3 to do the calcualtion)
But i tried the same code

```
 R = I(:,:,1);
 G = I(:,:,2);
 B = I(:,:,3);
 Samples = [Samples; [R G B]];
```

to get me nx3 matrix instead i got a matrix the size of the image...i searched and read some these forums ,but noting like this i suppose.
I just need to know how to get the matrix then i can do

Comment: If you want to classify by colors, its way easier to use the HSV color space.

Comment: Yes it worked...thank you

Comment: Consider accepting my asnwer then ;)

Comment: But I didn't used the semicolon between R G and B....I just put space between them....won't the semicolon make it in column

Comment: Yes, sorry , my mistake. The semicolon will make a N*3x1 matrix

Comment: Okey then ...any reading material on that hsv color space... Links..

Comment: Have you tried wikipedia? its a fantastic source. You can find a bit more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685724/to-categorize-jet-colormap-by-pixels-of-some-colors/28691726#28691726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not unrolling your variables.

```
 R = I(:,:,1);
 G = I(:,:,2);
 B = I(:,:,3);
```

does extract the R,G and B channels, but they are still NxM size. You wan to "unroll" them using the colon operator:

```
Samples = [Samples; [R(:) G(:) B(:)]];
```

Also, the best color space to segment colors is HSV, not RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `reshape` command:

```
    [x,y,k] = size(I); % k will be 3 for an RGB-image
    I_reshaped = reshape(I, x*y, k);

    R = I_reshaped(:,1);
    G = I_reshaped(:,2);
    B = I_reshaped(:,3);
```